# PIP installs correctly but does nothing when executed

Tags: python, pip

I'm having trouble with Python. 
I downloaded Python and pip without error.
But when I run `pip install flask`, it just waits a second and goes back to the command prompt.
Same issue when I run `python -m pip install flask`.
However, it works when I run `py -m pip install flask`. 
Any ideas why this happens?  Thanks!

My path is as follows:

> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38
> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts

Message when installing pip.

```
Collecting pip
Using cached pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-20.1.1
```

Comment: So now that you have an up-to-date `pip` you should try again.

Comment: If you have more than one version of Python installed you must be sure to run the correct version when you use `pip`.

Answer (score 1):

You might have various versions of python. Can you just try your pip install by mentioning the version

> python3.7 -m pip install flask